# OpenMP even/odd decomposition of a nested loop

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, openmp

I have part in my code that could be done parallel, so I started to read about openMP and did these introduction examples. Now I am trying to apply it to the following problem, schematically presented here:

`Grid.h`

```
class Grid
{
public:
    // has a grid member variable
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> 2Dgrid;
    // modifies the components of the 2Dgrid, no push_back() etc. used what could possibly disturbe the use of openMP
    update_grid(int,int,int,in);

};
```

`Test.h`

```
class Test
{
public:
    Grid grid1;
    Grid grid2;
    update();
    repeat_update();
};
```

`Test.cc`

```
.
.
.
Test::repeat_update() {
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        update();

}



Test::update() {
    int colIndex = 0;
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int rowIndexPlusOne = rowIndex + 1;
    int colIndexPlusOne = colIndex + 1;

// DIRECTION_X (grid[0].size()), DIRECTION_Y (grid.size) are the size of the grid

    for (int i = 0; i < DIRECTION_Y; i++) {
        // periodic boundry conditions
        if (rowIndexPlusOne > DIRECTION_Y - 1)
            rowIndexPlusOne = 0;

        // The following could be done parallel!!!
        for (int j = 0; j < DIRECTION_X - 1; j++) {
             grid1.update_grid(rowIndex,colIndex,rowIndexPlusOne,colIndexPlusOne);
             grid2.update_grid(rowIndex,colIndex,rowIndexPlusOne,colIndexPlusOne);


            colIndexPlusOne++;
            colIndex++;
        }
        colIndex = 0;
        colIndexPlusOne = 1;
        rowIndex++;
        rowIndexPlusOne++;
    }


}
.
.
.
```

The thing is, the updates done in `Test::update(...)` could be done in a parallel manner, since the `Grid::update(...)` only depends on the nearest neighbour of the grid. So for example in the inner loop multiple threads could do the work for `colIndex = 0,2,4,...`, independetly, that would be the even decomposition. After That the odd indices `colIndex=1,3,5,...` could be updated. Then the outerloop iterates one forward and the updates in direction x could again be done parallel. I have 16 cores at disposel and doing the parallelization could be a nice time save. But I totally dont have the perspective to see how this could be done, mainly because I dont know how to keep track of the `colIndex`, `rowIndex`, etc, since `#pragma omp parallel for` is applied to the `i,j` indices. I Would be grateful if somebody can show me the path out of the darkness.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what `update_grid(int,int,int,int)` does, it's kinda tricky to give a definitive answer. You show an embedded pair of loops of the type

```
for(int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < X; j++)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and assert that the `j` loop can be done in parallel. This would be an example of fine grained [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity#Computing). You could alternatively parallelize the `i` loop, in what would be a more coarse grained parallelization. If the amount of work of each individual thread is roughly equal, the coarse graining method has the advantage of less overhead (assuming that the parallelization of the two loops is equivalent).

There are a few things that you have to be careful of when parallelizing the loops. For starters, you increment `colIndexPlusOne` and `colIndex` in the inner loop. If you have multiple threads and a single variable for `colIndexPlusOne` and `colIndex`, then each thread will increment the variable and/or have [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software). You can bypass that in several manners, either giving each thread a copy of the variable, or making the increment `atomic` or `critical`, or by removing the dependency of the variable altogether and calculating what it should be for each step of the loop on the fly.

I would start with parallelizing the entire `update` function as such:

```
Test::update()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int colIndex = 0;
        int colIndexPlusOne = colIndex + 1;

         // DIRECTION_X (grid[0].size()), DIRECTION_Y (grid.size) are the size of the grid
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < DIRECTION_Y; i++)
        {
            int rowIndex = i;
            int rowIndexPlusOne = rowIndex + 1;
            // periodic boundary conditions
            if (rowIndexPlusOne > DIRECTION_Y - 1)
                rowIndexPlusOne = 0;

            // The following could be done parallel!!!
            for (int j = 0; j < DIRECTION_X - 1; j++)
            {
                 grid1.update_grid(rowIndex,colIndex,rowIndexPlusOne,colIndexPlusOne);
                 grid2.update_grid(rowIndex,colIndex,rowIndexPlusOne,colIndexPlusOne);

                // The following two can be replaced by j and j+1...
                colIndexPlusOne++;
                colIndex++;
            }
            colIndex = 0;
            colIndexPlusOne = 1;
            // No longer needed:
            // rowIndex++;
            // rowIndexPlusOne++;
        }
    }

}
```

By placing `#pragma omp parallel` at the beginning, all the variables are local to each thread. Also, at the beginning of the `i` loop, I assigned `rowIndex = i`, as at least in the code shown, that is the case. The same could be done for the `j` loop and `colIndex`.